# data update issues in gridview in yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii, yii2

I have a table "attendance"  and when I perform create action on it ,it works  properly like the screen-shot below,[image]

In this form I have used jquery to disable form field 'time in' and 'time out'   if the status value is "Absent" or "Leave".
my jquery code is below

```
   <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#status_id").on('change', function() 
        {
            if($("#status_id").val()=='Absent' || $("#status_id").val()=='Leave')
            {
                $("#attendance-time_in").val('');
                  $('#attendance-time_in').attr('disabled', true);

                 $("#attendance-time_out").val('');
                 $('#attendance-time_out').attr('disabled', true);

            }
            else {
                 $("#attendance-time_in").val();
                    $('#attendance-time_in').attr('disabled', false);

                   $("#attendance-time_out").val();
                    $('#attendance-time_out').attr('disabled', false);

        }

        }); 
    });

</script>
```

and **_form.php code is**

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'status', ['inputOptions' => ['class' => 'form-control','id' => 'status_id']])
                ->dropDownList([ 'Present' => 'Present', 'Absent' => 'Absent', 'Leave' => 'Leave',], ['prompt' => 'Select status']); ?>

        <?=
        $form->field($model, 'time_in')->widget(TimePicker::classname(), [
            'name' => 'time_in',
            'options'=>[
                'id'=>'attendance-time_in',
            ],
        ]);
        ?>
        <?=
        $form->field($model, 'time_out')->widget(TimePicker::classname(), [
            'name' => 'time_out',
            'options'=>[
                'id'=>'attendance-time_out',
            ],
        ]);
        ?>
```

its works fine for create action but when i update any data  [image]

like if i update data of arsalan khalid ,and  i  put absent instead of present the jquery works properly but when i click on update button it does not update the 'time in' and 'time out' attributes while all other attributes gets updated.for 'time in' and 'time out' it takes the previous value that it have i.e 9:40am and 5:52pm but  i want it should have null values as i have selected "Absent" in status.
**AttendanceController Update Action**

public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

```
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Attendance models Rules**

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [[ 'staff_id'], 'integer'],
            [['daytime'], 'safe'],
           [['staff_id'], 'required'],
            [['status','time_in', 'time_out'], 'string', 'max' => 45]
        ];
    }
```

i am new in yii2.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is create another rule inside your Attendance model.

```
[['time_in', 'time_out'], 'filter', 'filter' => function ($value) {
    if($this->status_id == AbsentStatus->status_id)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return $value;
}],
```

This way, if the status_id is equal to the AbsentStatus, you set the value of time_in and time_out as null.

Edit: you should substitute 'AbsentStatus->status_id' in the condition to the value of the id of your absent status.

Comment: thanx it works....i used if condition as                                                     if($this->status=='Absent' || $this->status=='Leave')
                {
                    return null;
                }
                return $value;

Answer (score 2):

I think one problem is the html id name fo the fields

In Yii2 the html id of an input field inside an active form is, by default, formed automatically in the format `'classname-fieldname'` (all lowercase). 
eg: namimg  the model class =  "Customer" the filed name is like

```
<input type="text" id="customer-name" class="form-control" name="Customer[name]" maxlength="16">
```

Then your field id should named  'attendance-status_id' , 'attendance-timein_id',  and so on...

Try using this format for the html id

And second, just for test, modify your controller this way

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save(false)) {
```

adding `false` to save() in saving process are not involved the validation rules.

Comment: i try using this method but still failed. <?=
        $form->field($model, 'time_in')->widget(TimePicker::classname(), [
            'name' => 'time_in',
            'options'=>[
                'id'=>'attendance-time_in',
            ],
        ]);
        ?>

Comment: please show your model Attendance rules and your avtionUpdate  in AttendanceController. could not be a jquery/id problem

Comment: public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [[ 'staff_id'], 'integer'],
            [['daytime'], 'safe'],
           [['staff_id'], 'required'],
            [['status','time_in', 'time_out'], 'string', 'max' => 45]
        ];
    }

Comment: actionUpdate::                                                                                                       public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }

Comment: @raxa the best way is add the code to the question. please update the question and format the code properly

Comment: @raxa in script status_id also need format   #attendance-status_id. try and give a feedback

Comment: i also tried using id as  attendance-status but found same result

Comment: I try with save(false)  in controller & found same result ,but my problem solved  by adding additional rule in model.Thanx for your co-operation.